# ng-Show records of table on condition

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ng-show

I am trying to show rows and their sum of value of columns. It has three states on which condition held.

1) auto
2) live
3) autolive (not present in json, need auto and live combine in rows)

Conclusion:

On siteData.jobType==toggleValue if (toggleValue==auto ), it shows records of "auto"

On siteData.jobType==toggleValue (toggleValue==live ), it shows records of "live"

But on siteData.jobType==toggleValue (toggleValue==autolive ), it shows no record , coz autolive is not present in json

How can I achieve it to show combine records of auto and live?

**// custom toggle button https://github.com/tannerlinsley/nz-toggle**

```
<nz-toggle
tri-toggle
on-toggle="myFunction()"
ng-model="toggleValue"
val-true="'auto'"
val-false="'live'"
val-null="'autolive'">
</nz-toggle> 



<table class="table table-condensed" border ="1" >
<thead>
<tr>

<th>PiteId</th>
<th>PiteId</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th >Success</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="siteData in siteObject" ng-show="siteData.jobType==toggleValue"   >

<td>{{siteData.sid}}</td>
<td>{{siteData.PiteId}}</td>
<td>{{siteData.Type}}</td>
<td>{{siteData.Date}}</td>
<td  ng-init="siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess = siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess + siteData.countSuccess">{{siteData.countSuccess}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**json format**

```
siteObject =
    {
    "data": [
      {
          "sid": 1,
          "PiteId": "1~10-4-2017~15:13:40",
          "Type": "live",
          "Date": "2017-04-14T18:30:00.000Z",
          "countSuccess": 1
        },

      {
          "sid": 1,
          "PiteId": "1~10-4-2017~15:13:40",
          "Type": "auto",
          "Date": "2017-04-14T18:30:00.000Z",
          "countSuccess": 1
        }
    ]
    }
```

[image: records of auto type]

[image: records of live type]

I want all of them when i toggle autolive

Comment: have you tried looking at [angular filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) instead of `ng-show` in your table ?

Comment: @Theo
see I am new in angular, and if it apply then I don't know how ?

Comment: What you want is when autolive toggle is on, displaying all data ? (data with type auto AND type live) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this workaround: `ng-show="toggleValue.indexOf(siteData.jobType) > -1"`

Comment: Can you explain this ?

Comment: Your variable can contain 3 values based on your toggle control.. `live`, `auto` and `autolive`..so in this code `ng-show="toggleValue.indexOf(siteData.jobType) > -1"` it will check if your `toggleValue` contains any of your `jobType`, if it finds both it will return true for every record.

Comment: Thank you very much 

Do you know how total of success value calculate on basis of toggle?

<td  ng-init="siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess = siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess + siteData.countSuccess">{{siteData.countSuccess}}</td>

Comment: use: `ng-init="siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess = siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess + (toggleValue.indexOf(siteData.jobType) > -1 ? siteData.countSuccess : 0)"`..discard those records from adding up which are not getting displayed on the grid

Comment: I have used that but on toggle change it not updates value, it still remains same

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom filter function like this: (*can be named anything*)

```
<tr ng-repeat="siteData in siteObject.data | filter: customFilter">
```

And, in your controller, you can implement some custom logic for that. Something like this:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(obj) {
  if($scope.toggleValue !== 'autolive') {
    return obj.Type === $scope.toggleValue      
  } 
  return true;
}
```

That should do it!

Here's [**working codepen example**](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/KmKYeP?editors=1010#0)