# Calculate count of record value of table on ng-hide and ng-show

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I am trying to show rows and their **sum of value** of columns by ng-hide and ng-show mechanism. It has three states on which condition held.

1) auto

2) live

3) autolive (not present in json, need auto and live combine in rows)

**Conclusion:**

On siteData.jobType==toggleValue if (toggleValue==auto ), it shows records of "auto"

On siteData.jobType==toggleValue (toggleValue==live ), it shows records of "live"

But on siteData.jobType==toggleValue (toggleValue==autolive ), it shows combine result

Now, the problem is count is not performing on change of toggle value, it remains same of combined result when page load,
I want it to change on toggle.

On Type **auto** it should be : 4
On Type **live** it should be : 2

**In case of reference :** [ng-Show records of table on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43391175/ng-show-records-of-table-on-condition/43391784?noredirect=1#comment73844727_43391784)

**// custom toggle button https://github.com/tannerlinsley/nz-toggle**

```
<nz-toggle
tri-toggle
on-toggle="myFunction()"
ng-model="toggleValue"
val-true="'auto'"
val-false="'live'"
val-null="'autolive'">
</nz-toggle> 



<table class="table table-condensed" border ="1" >
<thead>
<tr>

<th>PiteId</th>
<th>PiteId</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th >Success</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="siteData in siteObject" ng-show="toggleValue.indexOf(siteData.jobType) > -1"  >

<td>{{siteData.sid}}</td>
<td>{{siteData.PiteId}}</td>
<td>{{siteData.Type}}</td>
<td>{{siteData.Date}}</td>
<td  ng-init="siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess = siteObject.total.siteData.countSuccess + siteData.countSuccess">{{siteData.countSuccess}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**json format**

```
siteObject =
    {
    "data": [
      {
          "sid": 1,
          "PiteId": "1~10-4-2017~15:13:40",
          "Type": "live",
          "Date": "2017-04-14T18:30:00.000Z",
          "countSuccess": 1
        },

      {
          "sid": 1,
          "PiteId": "1~10-4-2017~15:13:40",
          "Type": "auto",
          "Date": "2017-04-14T18:30:00.000Z",
          "countSuccess": 1
        }
    ]
    }
```

[image: Combined result]
[image: auto result]

[image: live result]

Comment: so you want to show the number of records currently displayed based on your toggle value. Is that right?

Comment: yes @tanmay  that exactly i want

Comment: added my answer. I hope this time you would go with what is correct way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-show` to render what is selected. You should use a proper filter. In this case, you would need to create a custom filter since you want all items to show when toggle value is `autolive`.

So a custom filter that works like this should do it:

```
$scope.customFilter = function(obj) {
  return $scope.toggleValue.indexOf(obj.Type) > -1;
}
```

And, in your HTML, you can have

```
<tr ng-repeat="siteData in sites = (siteObject.data | filter: customFilter)">
  ...
</tr>
...
<tr>
  <td ng-bind="getTotal(sites, 'countSuccess')"></td>
</tr>
```

which calls a function in your controller counting total success values,

```
$scope.getTotal = function(arr, attr) {
    var count = 0;
    angular.forEach(arr, function(val) {
      count += val[attr];
    })
    return count
}
```

Note how I passed the attribute `'countSuccess'` to the function and it uses that as attribute in `val[attr]`. Now, similarly, you can pass other attribute for fail (maybe `countFailure`) and get that value.

Funny enough, I had mentioned this approach of using `filter` instead of `ng-show` in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43391834/4315380) as well, but you seemed to go with `ng-show` there :)

Here's your [**working codepen**](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/KmKYeP?editors=1010#0) (updated, for dynamic attribute)

Comment: you moved in wrong direction, we need to count value of Success not number of rows on change toggle

Comment: yes , sorry for miscommunication
see above question , you will get it from 3 images, I posted

Comment: If we have 1 more field like Fail and we want to apply same operation but using same function can we do that ?
or we will make getFailCount function again for summation

Comment: @Creator updated answer with that. please upvote too if it helped

Comment: very well explained

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this. it's better use of filter instead of `ng-show` directive. and use size of filtered data for total sites.

```
<tr ng-repeat="siteData  in filtered = (siteObject.data | filter:
 {Type:toggleValue})" >
  <td>{{siteData.Date}}</td>
  <td >{{filtered.length}}</td>
</tr>
```

<kbd>[***DEMO***](http://plnkr.co/edit/vyZHl6YYFEeTeRvurs9d?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: you moved in wrong direction, we need to count value of Success not number of rows on change toggle

Summation of value of countSuccess

Comment: autolive should not be present in json

Comment: please see updated answer. http://plnkr.co/edit/vyZHl6YYFEeTeRvurs9d?p=preview. i remove 'autolive'.

Comment: If we have 1 more field like Fail and we want to apply same operation but using same function can we do that ?